# how can I track down the actual source of an EPIPE write error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq, rabbit.js

I'm sending a fairly large message to a RabbitMQ queue. I suspect the message may be too large but the error that I'm getting seems to have nothing to do with that. I'm using Rabbit.js. Is this an example of a library failing to catch an error? How can I figure out where the error is actually happening?

The relevant block of code in net.js:

```
if (status < 0) {
    var ex = exceptionWithHostPort(status, 'write', req.address, req.port);
    debug('write failure', ex);
    self._destroy(ex, req.cb);
    return;
  }
```

`status` is equal to `-32`. That's... not much help. `req.address` and `req.port` are both undefined.

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write EPIPE
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:763:14)
```

If this is a problem with the Rabbit.js library I'd like to be able to give the author more info than that stack trace (which seems like it wouldn't help much at all).

Comment: Might help: https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream_spy or https://www.npmjs.com/package/vstream

Comment: Might clarify and help to track the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35641655/1064325